# Can subdomain and bounded context be same in domain driven design?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I understand that subdomains exist in the problem space and refine it to break down the complexity whereas bounded contexts exist in the solution space and are represented as explicit domain models in a context. But I am still confused why we can't have subdomains as bounded context? or do bounded contexts exist inside a subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly understand the difference between the problem space and the solution space like stated in your question I'm wondering why you're asking this.

"But I am still confused why we can't have subdomains as bounded context?"

This is just like saying "why can't we have questions as answers?".

A subdomain is a problem of a larger domain and a bounded context is the solution space where that problem will get solved in practice. You should strive to have a 1 to 1 alignment between subdomains and bounded contexts, just like you would ideally have a 1 to 1 alignment between questions and answers.

However, as developers we need to be pragmatic and it's always possible in practice that a single bounded context covers multiple subdomains. Still, that would increase the risk of terms overloading since multiple subdomains would be expressed through the same ubiquitous language (UL).

Just to make it clear, the UL, the code, the chosen storage mechanisms, etc. all lives in a bounded context: those things are part of the solution.

Comment: It was mentioned in a book that though bounded context and subdomains are different, bounded context can fall under a subdomain. This got me a little confused.

Comment: @AditGupta Which book? I'm not entirely sure what the author meant with that statement and I agree that is confusing.

Comment: Patterns, Principles and Practices of Domain Driven Design - http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Patterns-Principles-and-Practices-of-Domain-Driven-Design.productCd-1118714709.html

Comment: @AditGupta It might be worth asking the author through the forums. I read the book as well but I must have ignored that.